# DRBD setup problem

Tags: drbd

I'm so new to DRBD, please help me fixing the problem below. Enclosed my drbd.conf. Many thanks

```
[root@skonkwerks1 ~]# drbdadm create-md all
open(/dev/hdb3) failed: No such file or directory
Command 'drbdmeta /dev/drbd0 v08 /dev/hdb3 internal create-md' terminated with exit code 20
drbdsetup exited with code 20
```

```
[root@skonkwerks1 ~]# vi /etc/drbd.conf
global { usage-count no; }
resource repdata {
        protocol C;
        startup { wfc-timeout 0; degr-wfc-timeout   120; }
        disk { on-io-error detach; } # or panic
        # net { cram-hmac-alg "hdd1"; shared-secret "testing"; }
        syncer { rate 10M; }
        on skonkwerks1 {
                device /dev/drbd0;
                disk /dev/hdb1;
                address 172.29.156.1:7788;
                meta-disk internal;
        }
        on skonkwerks2 {
                device /dev/drbd0;
                disk /dev/hdb1;
                address 172.29.156.2:7788;
                meta-disk internal;
        }
}
```

Comment: Where does that **hdb3** come from? What does `drbdadm dump all` show?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it can help, but I used "drbdadm create-md" with the name of the resources,
so in your case

```
  drbdadm create-md repdata
```